# Using nested namespaces for readability, a bad idea?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here's an example (not what I am doing exactly, but hopefully gets the point across).

```
namespace SDL{
    namespace Surface{
        void blit(SDL_Surface *src, SDL_Surface *dest);
    }
    namespace Audio{
        Mix_Chunk* load_sound(const char *file);
    }
    namespace Color{
        SDL_Color mix(int r, int b, int g);
    }
}
```

I don't fear name clashes since I am writing it all myself but for readability-- I think it is more clear. Would this be considered bad practice? Better off all within the SDL namespace? Which is considered better style?

Comment: If you ask five software developers how they think namespaces should be organized, you'll get no fewer than seven different answers.

Comment: Nested namespaces are pretty common and are neither "good" nor "bad." Namespaces are just syntactic sugar (albeit useful sugar), and it's up to the engineer to use them wisely or foolishly.

Comment: Clearly belongs on *programmers* (if at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good comment James :-)

Personally I like them because I never ever use 'using' statements. This IMHO it makes code more readable as  you can instantly see where this functions resides etc

eg

```
 int price=StockExchange::CME::GetPrice();
 Database::Mysql::StorePrice(price);
```

Comment: `Alternatively::It::Means::That::You::Can::End::Up::Stuck::With::Ridiculously::Long::Names::That::Make::Your::Code::Really::Wide()`.

Comment: Programmers have a knack of making good features go bad :-) Wide is becoming less of an issue every day though, terminal > 80, adjustable windows, 24" wide screen monitors becoming standard.